# Can you use css to resize and crop background images instantaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I have come across a problem while trying to make a background for my website. I am trying to have an image that can be scrolled and resized as seen on: https://sketchthemes.com/preview/?theme=98. 
I have tried this:

```
<div id="back_img" style="background-image: url("test.jpg");"></div>
```

And then setting the style to:

```
#back_img {

  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

But this does not contain all of the functionalities I wished for.

Comment: _"trying to have an image that can be scrolled and resized as seen on"_ Not certain which effect you are referencing?

Comment: @guest271314 Look on the link I posted and look at the initial background image

Answer (score 1):

Setting background-attachment: fixed; and background-size: cover; will bring it closer to that effect, however to get the parallax scrolling you will need to write / use a script to adjust it's position based on the current scroll.

```
#back_img {

  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you greatly! Do you have any idea if there is a premade script for that?

Comment: There are lots. I've used this one in the past: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/